# Symfony create checkbox and radio button manually without form generator

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox

I need to create checkbox and radio button manually, without generator. This is my code :

```
          {% for d in items %}
                        <div class="inline field">
                            <div class="ui checkbox">
                                <input 
                                    type="checkbox" 
                                    {% if d.isComplete %}checked{% endif %} 
                                    tabindex="0" 
                                    class="hidden"
                                    name="cbx_{{d.id}}"
                                    >
                                <label>{{d.nama}}
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <i class="trash icon"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

That's my example code of checkbox,

please help how to create it properly and create submit action that can get all checked. I tried using this code on server side :

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) 
{
            $cbx_1 = $request->get("cbx_1");
}
```

and it too brute, please help me how to make it properly.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Ids as values :

```
     {% for d in items %}
                    <div class="inline field">
                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                            <input 
                                type="checkbox" 
                                {% if d.isComplete %}checked{% endif %} 
                                tabindex="0" 
                                class="hidden"
                                name="cbx[]"
                                value="{{d.id}}"
                                >
                            <label>{{d.nama}}
                                <a href="#">
                                    <i class="trash icon"></i>
                                </a>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
     {% endfor %}
```

After that, you can easily get the selected values:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) 
{
  $cbx= $request->get("cbx"); //Array of selected values
}
```